# How to open the secure settings of the android phone with my ionic 2 app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 and the secureStorage plugin. The problem is that with Android, the device has to be secured with a code to use secure storage.

In the documentation it has:

```
var ss;
var _init = function () {
    ss = new cordova.plugins.SecureStorage(
        function () {
            console.log('OK');
        },
        function () {
            navigator.notification.alert(
                'Please enable the screen lock on your device. This app cannot operate securely without it.',
                function () {
                    ss.secureDevice(
                        function () {
                            _init();
                        },
                        function () {
                            _init();
                        }
                    );
                },
                'Screen lock is disabled'
            );
        },
        'my_app');
};
_init();
```

But I'm not using ionic 1 but ionic 2. How to call the secureDevice method?

I do anything like:

```
this.secureStorage.create('myStorage')
                .then((storage: SecureStorageObject) => {
                    storage.set('var', 'toto')
                        .then(
                        () => console.log('ok),
                        (e) => console.log('error');
                        );
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.error('The device is not secured');
                })
```

I can detect in the catch that the device is not secured. But how can I add next to my console.err a call to the secureDevice method?

The documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage/

Comment: Raised an issue with [ionic](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/1625) just in case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was [raised and fixed](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/1625) so you can use the latest version of `@ionic-native/SecureStorage`.

**If you are unable to update the ionic-native wrapper, read further**.

`secureDevice` function doesnt seem to be added in the [ionic-native wrapper](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/secure-storage/index.ts) though its available in the [cordova plugin](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage/blob/master/www/securestorage.js#L266).

You *could* think of using the cordova plugin without the wrapper.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-secure-storage --save
```

Immediately after the imports and before the class, declare the object .

```
declare var cordova:any;
```

And use [the plugin api](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage#-plugin-api) within  platform ready().

```
this.platform.ready().then(() =>{
   this.ss =  new cordova.plugins.SecureStorage(
() => { console.log('Success')},
(error) => { 
   console.log('Error ' + error);
   //call here..
   this.ss.secureDevice(()=>{},()=>{});
 },
'myStorage');
});
```

Comment: will this answer avoids this `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Device is not secure
Error: Device is not secure` issue

Comment: @MohanGopi if you are using secure device.. it should

Comment: is there any way we can avoid forcing screen lock for device

Comment: Using secureStorage seems to include screen locking. You could check with the plugin maintainer